# Segregating results per iteration of a loop

Tags: java, loops

I've got an assignment which is to simulate a basketball free throw shooter's percentage of made shots across 5 games with 10 shots per game. For the most part the code is working how I want it to but for each game I need print out the number of `in` shots out of 10. I cannot figure out how to keep this result specific to the correlating `game` rather than increasing the `in` number across all games. Each following game is adding its `in` amount to the previous game's.

Then I also need help on calling out the best and worst scores based on the number of `in` shots for each game. I believe the two problems can be solved by the same action, I'm just having trouble finding what action that needs to be.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Final2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double in;
        int out;
        int count;
        int games;
        int tries;
        double average;
        int total;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        count = 0;
        in = 0;
        average = 0;
        total = 0;
        games = 1;

        do{             
            System.out.println("\nGame " + games + ":");
            games++;

            for (tries = 0; tries < 10; tries++){
                int shot = (int)(Math.random()*100);
                count++;

                if (shot < input){
                   in++;
                    System.out.print("IN ");
                }   

                else{
                    System.out.print("OUT ");
                }               
            }
            System.out.println("\nFree Throws Made: " + String.format("%.0f", in) + " Out Of 10. ");
        }   
        while (games <= 5);{
        }           
        average = (in / count)*100;

        System.out.println("\nSummary:");
        System.out.println("Best Game Free Throws Made: " + "...");
        System.out.println("Worst Game Free Throws Made: " + "...");
        System.out.println("Total Free Throws Made: " + String.format("%.0f", in) + " Out Of " + count);
        System.out.println("Average Free Throw Percentage: " + String.format("%.0f", average) + "%");       
        System.out.println("\nEND OF SIMULATION!");     
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: 50

Game 1:
IN IN IN IN IN IN IN OUT OUT OUT 
Free Throws Made: 7 Out Of 10. 

Game 2:
OUT IN OUT OUT OUT IN OUT IN IN IN 
Free Throws Made: 12 Out Of 10. 

Game 3:
IN OUT IN IN IN OUT OUT OUT OUT OUT 
Free Throws Made: 16 Out Of 10. 

Game 4:
IN OUT OUT OUT IN OUT OUT OUT IN IN 
Free Throws Made: 20 Out Of 10. 

Game 5:
OUT OUT IN OUT OUT OUT IN IN IN IN 
Free Throws Made: 25 Out Of 10. 

Summary:
Best Game Free Throws Made: ...
Worst Game Free Throws Made: ...
Total Free Throws Made: 25 Out Of 50
Average Free Throw Percentage: 50%

END OF SIMULATION!
```

Comment: `average = (in / count)*100;` - see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reset the `in` variable before the while. If you want to keep track of the total number of in you have to use a new variable (ex. `total_in`).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Final2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int in = 0;
        double total_in = 0;
        int out;
        int count = 0;
        int games = 1;
        int tries;
        double average = 0;
        int total = 0;

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
            int input = scan.nextInt();

            do{             
                System.out.println("\nGame " + games + ":");
                games++;

                for (tries = 0; tries < 10; tries++){
                    int shot = (int)(Math.random()*100);
                    count++;

                    if (shot < input){
                       in++;
                        System.out.print("IN ");
                    }   

                    else{
                        System.out.print("OUT ");
                    }               
                }
                System.out.println("\nFree Throws Made: " + String.format("%.0f", in) + " Out Of 10. ");
                total_in += in;
                in = 0;
            }   
            while (games <= 5);{
            }           
            average = (total_in / count)*100;

        System.out.println("\nSummary:");
        System.out.println("Best Game Free Throws Made: " + "...");
        System.out.println("Worst Game Free Throws Made: " + "...");
        System.out.println("Total Free Throws Made: " + String.format("%.0f", total_in) + " Out Of " + count);
        System.out.println("Average Free Throw Percentage: " + String.format("%.0f", average) + "%");       
        System.out.println("\nEND OF SIMULATION!");     
    }
}
```

Comment: That definitely helped! Thank you! The solution was not difficult but i could not seem to come up with it!  Now to solve the last issue. Thanks again!